# Sending data with post method to another site

Tags: php, post, bots

I wanna send some variables to another server with post method. I made a code and it worked on my localhost. But I cannot made it work for another site.

```
<form name='myform' action='#' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='intnumber' value='15'>
       <a id='Link' onclick='document.myform.submit()' href='#'>Go!</a>
</form>
```

I wanna get keywords to my site automaticly. I use Ubersuggest site manual but it takes long time add keywords manually. So, I wanna send ubersuggest.org post form to search keywords and take the keywords with php bot. I prepared a code for search part, it is not working:

```
<form name='uberform' action='http://www.ubersuggest.org/' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='query' value='game'>
    <input type='hidden' name='language' value='English/UK'>
    <input type='hidden' name='source' value='web'>
       <a id='Link' onclick='document.uberform.submit()' href='#'>Go!</a>
</form>
```

Please help me for correcting this code. 
NOTE: I want to use this site just personally, i will not make any profit. And I dont want attack etc. to this site, cos' i love it and i use it!

Comment: Cross site POSTING is not allowed, unless it is explicitly defined by the receiving end.

Comment: Cross site posting is ALLOWED. Thats how most popular payment gateways work!

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.  Post to other domains is not allowed.

Comment: Post to other domains is allowed

Comment: Can the curl functions send this data? Can I send form data with any other way?

Comment: @Broncha,  Agree.  cURL actually uses it.  I added my first part of my post, but couldn't save since it wasn't enough text.  Don't ask me why I added that blurb about not being allowed!